# How to Fade out with CSS Transition (Managed to fade in, but don't understand how to fade out without "Webkit")

Tags: html, css

I have tried searching for this but cannot find it.
I have created a class which when hovered over the pararaph element zooms in and decreases opacity. I have use a transition on this of (.5s). This works really well.
However I have seen (I watched a video) that you can create a transition for after the hover.
I have been trying to use:

```
image:hover:after p {
  transition: .5s;
}
```

But it is not working. I do not understand these webkit options. And I have seen this done without the use of webkit. Basically, is it possible without webkit? Or is it my imagination?

If webkit is the only way could someone link me to some AWESOME tutorials.

This is what I currently have in my stylesheet :

```
.image p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .3);
}


.image:hover p {
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .9);
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Maybe you are confusing something here. Do you mean the timely "after" as in "as soon as the hover effect ends" or are you really talking about the pseudo-element `:after` being a html component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this

```
.image p {
    transition: .5s ease-out
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That has done it! Simple and easy! Thank you so much! So glad I asked. Wish I could give you more than one like!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.image p a {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.image p a:hover {
  -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
  -moz-opacity: 0.25;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <p><a>fade in fade out effect on hover element</a> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use css3 transition effect and use opacity for fading the element

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `transition` property to the normal selector not the hover; Otherwise the transition effect will only applied when you're *hovered* over not moused out..

e.g.

```
.image p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .3);
  transition: 0.5s;
}


.image:hover p {
  background: rgba(235, 229, 235, .9);
  font-size: 110%;
}
```